# Very large var/log/apache2/deflate_log file

Tags: apache2

The file `/var/log/apache2/deflate_log` is taking up 8G!

Is it safe to remove it?

How to proceed to remove and prevent it from growing this large?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to rotate the log regularly if necessary (look for logrotate configuration). For now - I'd recommend emptying the file rather then removing it (it can be still open for writing; removing such file will lead to some "inconsistencies" in the system - while file will be removed from the filesystem, the access will still be allocated for the process to write to it and space will not be really emptied/returned to the system/disk unless process is restarted freeing the space - ooph, I guess this sentence may look a bit complicated ;), but it's, in fact, fairly simple)

To empty the log run the following command:  >/var/log/apache2/deflate_log

just be careful, not to erase something else by mistake.

In this way anyway you won't need to restart apache.

Comment: Thanks! I truncated the file as suggested and changed the http config to add a `.log` extension to it. Now I think it will be rotated.